# How to calculate the percentage of any given value in C?

Tags: c

I have created a program following "C - how to program - Dietel & Dietel" book. Its and Heart Rate calculator. Its gets the current date and the birth date. Then it calculates the maximum Heart Rate with this formula.

> (maxHR = 220 - age))

Now i want to display the Range of Hearth Rate from 50% to 85% using the value saved in maxHR. But i am unable to think of how to calculate the average. What should be the formula?

Please Help.

```
int main(void) {

int currentYear, year, currentMonth, month, currentDay, day, age, maxHR;
float minRange, maxRange;

printf("Enter Current Year Month and Day: "); scanf("%d%d%d", &currentYear, &currentMonth, &currentDay);
printf("Enter Birth Year Month and Day: "); scanf("%d%d%d", &year, &month, &day);
printf("---------------------------------------------------\n");

printf("Age is: %d Year(s).\n", (age = currentYear - year));
printf("Maximum Heart Rate: %d\n", (maxHR = 220 - age));
printf("---------------------------------------------------\n");
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use this formula for 50% range (directly in your printf line):

```
minRange = (0.50*maxHR);
```

and use this for 85%:

```
maxRange = (0.85*maxHR);
```